# Does $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$?

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

> Does $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$?

My answer is: No

because obviously $f_n(0) = 0$ and $f_n(1)=\frac{1}{2}$, so for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ it's true that for $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{4}$: $f_n(1)-f_n(0) > \varepsilon$.

Is this question stupid or am I?

Comment: What is $f(x)$? You meant to say $f_n(x)$ right?

Comment: Yes, I meant $f_n(x)$

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Instead, you could  find the pointwise limit function $f$ (what is its value for $0<x<1$?) and note it's not continuous.

Comment: @DavidMitra, Why isn't it true?

Comment: To show uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ to $f$, you would have to show  $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ is small for all $x$ and all sufficiently large $n$. That's far from what you wrote...

Comment: Got it. Thank you @DavidMitra!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the summary is this,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & x\in [0, 1)\\ 
 \frac{1}{2}& x = 1 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Each $f_n$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, yet the limit is ....

Also to correct your logic, consider this example. Let $g_n(x) = x^3 + 1/n$, then $$g_n(x) \rightrightarrows  x^3 = g(x).$$

Now $g_n(1) = 1 + 1/n$ and $g_n(0) = 1/n$, but according to your logic we would have $g_n(0) - g_n(1) = 1 \nleq \epsilon = 1/4.$

Answer (score 1):

Neither, look back at the definition of uniform convergence of functions.

Comment: Thank you for the credit of not being stupid :)

Comment: It doesn't help to think you're stupid weather you are or not.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: note that $f_n(x) \le x^n$ so for $x\in[0,1)$, $f_n(x)\to 0$ pointwise on this interval. You already noted that $f_n(1) = \frac{1}{2}$. Do you see how this helps?

Comment: Yes, I understand now. If $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly it must be to $0$, BUT $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$. Hence, for every $n$: $\left|f_n(1)- 0\right| = \frac{1}{2}$